# Convert newline delimited JSON object into JSON object using java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have to load the following newline delimited JSON object into the Dynamodb table.

```
{"car":0,"trip":0,"x":172,"y":43,"speed":10,"createdAt":"2019-01-01T21:47:10Z"}
{"car":0,"trip":0,"x":173,"y":44,"speed":15,"createdAt":"2019-01-01T21:48:10Z"}
{"car":0,"trip":0,"x":174,"y":45,"speed":20,"createdAt":"2019-01-01T21:49:10Z"}
{"car":0,"trip":1,"x":272,"y":53,"speed":20,"createdAt":"2019-01-02T21:57:10Z"}
{"car":0,"trip":1,"x":273,"y":54,"speed":25,"createdAt":"2019-01-02T21:58:10Z"}
{"car":0,"trip":1,"x":274,"y":55,"speed":30,"createdAt":"2019-01-02T21:59:10Z"}
```

car and trip are unique identifiers.

If I load the above object row by row in sequence then last row for the unique car and trip is loaded in the DynamoDB table. The final data in the table is given below:

```
{"car":0,"trip":0,"x":174,"y":45,"speed":20,"createdAt":"2019-01-01T21:49:10Z"}
{"car":0,"trip":1,"x":274,"y":55,"speed":30,"createdAt":"2019-01-02T21:59:10Z"}
```

The requirement is to load data in following format.

```
[
  {
   "car":0,
   "trip":0,
   "event": {
      "x": ["172","173","174"]
      "y": ["43","44","45"]
      "speed": ["10","15","20"]
      "createdAt": ["2019-01-01T21:47:10Z","2019-01-01T21:48:10Z","2019-01-01T21:49:10Z"]
     }
  },
  {
   "car":0,
   "trip":1,
   "event": {
      "x": ["272","273","274"]
      "y": ["53","54","55"]
      "speed": ["20","25","20"]
      "createdAt": ["2019-01-02T21:57:10Z","2019-01-02T21:58:10Z","2019-01-02T21:59:10Z"]
     }
  }
]
```

What is the best method to load given newline delimited JSON object into DynamoDB in the required format using java?

Answer (score 2):

Your output structure is somewhat different than the input and hence just adding it to list and converting to JSON will not solve the problem. The reason you are seeing only 2 entries in dynamo DB is I assume you are making a composite key for `car-trip` so only the last entries are saved(I am not much familiar with dynamo db though.
I am first saving all entries to a map with a complex composite key of more attribute(this is slower and not much efficient) and then composing the final map to generate output. Here is how I tried to do it:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Data
class CarTrip {
    private int car;
    private int trip;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int speed;
    private String createdAt;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CarTrip{" +
                "car=" + car +
                ", trip=" + trip +
                ", x=" + x +
                ", y=" + y +
                '}';
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class CarTripDynamoDb {
    private int car;
    private int trip;
    private CarTripEvent event;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class CarTripEvent {
    private List<String> x = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> y = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> speed = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> createdDates = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addX(String xItem) {
        x.add(xItem);
    }

    public void addY(String yItem) {
        y.add(yItem);
    }

    public void addSpeed(String speedItem) {
        speed.add(speedItem);
    }

    public void addCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        this.createdDates.add(createdDate);
    }
}

public class SampleMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        //Reading and transforming to object
        List<CarTrip> carTrips = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("data.json")).stream()
                .map(l -> gson.fromJson(l, CarTrip.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //Create Map of composite keys and objecy
        Map<String, CarTrip> tripMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (CarTrip carTrip : carTrips) {
            final String key = generateMapKey(carTrip.getCar(), carTrip.getTrip(), carTrip.getX(), carTrip.getY(), carTrip.getSpeed());
            tripMap.put(key, carTrip);
        }

        // Create Output map
        Map<String, CarTripDynamoDb> tripDynamoDbMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, CarTrip> entry : tripMap.entrySet()) {
            final CarTrip value = entry.getValue();
            final String newKey = "car-" + value.getCar() + "-trip-" + value.getTrip();
            if (tripDynamoDbMap.get(newKey) != null) {
                final CarTripDynamoDb carTripDynamoDb = tripDynamoDbMap.get(newKey);
                final CarTripEvent event = carTripDynamoDb.getEvent();
                updateEventFromTrips(value, event);
                carTripDynamoDb.setEvent(event);
                tripDynamoDbMap.put(newKey, carTripDynamoDb);
            } else {
                CarTripEvent event = new CarTripEvent();
                updateEventFromTrips(value, event);
                tripDynamoDbMap.put(newKey, new CarTripDynamoDb(value.getCar(), value.getTrip(), event));
            }
        }

        //Result
        List<CarTripDynamoDb> carTripEvents = tripDynamoDbMap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(carTripEvents));
    }

    private static void updateEventFromTrips(CarTrip value, CarTripEvent event) {
        event.addX(String.valueOf(value.getX()));
        event.addY(String.valueOf(value.getY()));
        event.addSpeed(String.valueOf(value.getSpeed()));
        event.addCreatedDate(value.getCreatedAt());
    }

    private static String generateMapKey(int... compositeIds) {
        final StringBuilder keyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int id : compositeIds) {
            keyBuilder.append(id).append("-");
        }
        return keyBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

The following code snippet should help

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

GsonBuilder builder = GsonBuilderUtils.gsonBuilderWithBase64EncodedByteArrays();
builder.setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(obj)

where obj the result object returned.

Comment: Sorry! Your answer is not clear. Could you please elaborate with an example using the above scenario?

Comment: your question is iself is not clear, the "events" in the requirement section is missing out.  If it involves java code there should be a List<Object> formed as a result. Just give taht List<Object> as input to GsonBuilder instance.